# By default, Shipping information fields should be shown

Tags: commerce

In Drupal commerce kickstart Checkout page, by default Shipping information fields should show and the checkbox should uncheck. I tried JavaScript, but it is not working. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Go to Store Settings -> Checkout settings
2) Click the configure link for "Shipping information"
3) On the configure page,  uncheck the "Make copying information from this profile the default action, requiring users to uncheck a box on the checkout pane to enter a different address." checkbox.